# Accordion panels

Tags: jquery, accordion

I am not good with jQuery. I found the following accordion panel script. This script hides all panels on load and open one when I click on it. However, I want to have all panels open on load and only click the one I want to hide.  don't want to hide all when I click on it.

```
// accordion
    $('.accordion h5').click(function () {
        $('.accordion h5').removeClass('open');
     // close all slides
        $('.accordion ul ul').slideUp('normal');
        if ($(this).next().is(':hidden') == true) {
            $(this).addClass('open');
            $(this).next().slideDown('normal');
        }
    });
    $('.accordion h5').mouseover(function () {
        $(this).addClass('hover');
    }).mouseout(function () {
        $(this).removeClass('hover');
    });
    $('.accordion ul ul').show();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following should give behavior you want.

```
 $('.accordion h5').click(function () {
        $(this).toggleClass('open').next().slideToggle(); 
 }).hover(function(){
       $(this).toggleClass('hover');    
 });
```

Provide some markup if this needs to be modified